# Alternative way to Write Stream Prolog

Tags: variables, stream, prolog

i'm looking for an alternative way to print a prolog variable in a txt or other text formats; or just save the local variable somewhere. I've already used Write Stream, but I have had some problems so I hope there's another way to do that.

For example:

```
ask(Q, Answer) :-
  open('text8.txt',write,Stream),
  write(Stream,Q), 
  write(Stream,'?\nEnd'), close(Stream).
```

Comment: What problems are you having?

Comment: txt Stream works fine with prolog, but with a particular function (recursive whit a lot of calls) I have problems in Java using jpl libraries. My application is not able too write in txt file (i have this problem only using java, direclty, on pl it works). I need and alternative way to write in txt or other format

Comment: Would it make more sense to use JPL to do the back-end work, then use Java to do the writing of results to a file?

Comment: I think - simply pass the *fullpath* to open/3. Probably it's only a permission problem due to the folder location of process being not writable